# how to install php on ubuntu?

Tags: php, ubuntu, lamp

i've followed the link: http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-apache2-with-php5-and-mysql-support-on-ubuntu-10.10-lamp in order to install php on ubuntu 10.10. The problem is that the linl: http://192.168.0.100 is not working "could not connect to 192.168.0.100". need sime help. appreciate

Comment: Quote: "In this tutorial I use the hostname server1.example.com with the IP address 192.168.0.100. These __settings might differ for you, so you have to replace them where appropriate__.".

Comment: Did you try with http://localhost/ or http://127.0.0.1/? Or else open a console, type ifconfig, find your IP and try with that? Of course as other said your IP may not be 192.168.0.100 so maybe that's the cause your browser doesnt connect the url you posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quote the guide you link to:

> In this tutorial I use the hostname server1.example.com with the IP address 192.168.0.100. These settings might differ for you, so **you have to replace them where appropriate**

(With whatever hostname and ip address your server has assigned)

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace the example server address with you own server address. It is that simple :)

Answer (score 0):

http://192.168.0.100/ is just an example IP and is unlikely to be the one you should be using.

If Ubuntu is installed on the same machine as your web browser on, you should try http://127.0.0.1/, which is the IP address of the local host.

If it's on another machine, you can use type this into the teminal

```
ifconfig
```

to determine your IP address. In my case:

```
wlan1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:00:5C:52:C4  
      inet addr:192.168.178.31  Bcast:192.168.178.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: 2001:44b8:3110:f300:215:ff:fe5c:52c4/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: fe80::215:ff:fe5c:52c4/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:146164 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:112102 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:87766574 (83.7 MiB)  TX bytes:24386471 (23.2 MiB)
```

This means that the IP I should use in my browser would be http://192.168.178.31/

Please let us know how you get on.